# Can i hook up 2 guitars to the droptune box and send individual signals to 2 different amps?

Tags: amplifiers, effects-pedal

Can i hook up 2 guitars to the droptune box and send individual signals to 2 different amps? My bass player and fuitar player both have the digitec droptune box and i only play guitar on a few songs and dont want to buy a drop box if i can help it so im trying to figure out a way if possible to plus my guitar into my bass players drop box and split the out going signals to go into two different amps but both utilizing the same droptune box...

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to use both guitars simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [this pedal](http://digitech.com/en/products/the-drop), and you want to play both simultaneously, then no.

It only has a single input and a single output, and you won't be able to mix and then unmix the two signals.

Alternately, you could swap cables (manually, or with another pedal), but that's going to be clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can do this, however it uses a clumsy workaround and I wouldn't suggest doing it.

What you need is a variant of an AB pedal (which switches inputs or outputs) that can cope with simultaneous switching of inputs **and** outputs.

So in one state it has the bass routed to the droptuner and then to the bass amp.

When you press the button it then needs to route the bass directly to the amp, but take your guitar input to the droptuner and then route its output to the guitar amp.

Totally do-able, yes, and there are products out there which do multiple switching, but they aren't cheap.

I'd suggest just buying a droptuner yourself. You can pick them up quite cheaply second hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could contrive a switching arrangement that would be the equivalent of swapping cables from his guitar and amp to your guitar and amp.  But that is all it would do.  It wouldn't magically mix your signals together and then un-mix them so that you could both play your own guitat through the same box into your own amp at the same time.